# Generic data list in C++

Tags: c++, list, pointers, generics

I'm working with Lists using C++ and I had a little doubt. Each Cell have a pointer to next cell and your data. Now each cell is using the class Data1.

```
class Data1
{
    public:
        int item1;
};

class Data2
{
    public:
        int item2;
};

class List
{

    /* Each cell of list */
    typedef class Cell
    {
        public:
            class Data1 data;
            class Cell *next;

    }Cell;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

How can I generic it to use Data1 or Data2 for diferent applications?

A better explaination is if Data2 are on another source code and the Cell point to Data2 not Data1.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use templates for this:

```
template<class Data>
class List
{
    struct Cell { Data data; Cell* next; };
};
```

At instantiation time you can pass the intended class to be used as the type of `data`:

```
List<Data1> list1;
List<Data2> list2;
```

Also, you don't need the prefix `class` or `struct` when defining instances of classes in C++.

Comment: This helps a lot! I have one last question. I have created a main and incialize like you said: List<Data1> list1; but when I try to compile this error insist: (...) undefined reference to List<Data>::List(). I picked the constructor for a example, but all my functions on list.cpp get this error. I know that the error is to link correctly but I don't know how to processed.

Comment: @marquesm91 Since your class is a template, you need to keep the implementation of your constructors/functions/etc. inside the `.cpp` file. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) for more information.